# What graph to plot in order to meet theinstructions and apply the Bellman algo?

Tags: graphs

I'm actually studying the Bellman algorithm. I have to draw a graph from this array.

\begin{array}{|l|c|r|B|d|}
Rhythme & A & B& C& D\\
\hline
Normal & 5 & - & - & -\\
Rapide & 4 & 3 & 5 & 2\\
Prioritaire & 2 & 2 & 3 & 1\\
\end{array}

The instructions are: each vertex corresponds to a **possible** progress where some phases has been realised using some amounts (thus a vertex is characterized by the last phase done and the total amount spent to realize the phases). Each edges are valued by costs.

My question is: do I have to plot a graph like this one?

[image]

Or this one

[image]